# Wortwahl in "133 Prozent beträgt ___ der Deutschen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Aus der Hohlspiegel-Kolumne im Spiegel-Magazin:

> 133 Prozent beträgt das Wachstum der Deutschen, die mit Airbnb reisten.

Wie könnte man den Satz umschreiben, damit er nicht in der Kolumne landet? Sollte man "der Zuwachs" statt "das Wachstum" benutzen? Klingt "das Wachstum der Deutschen" so lustig?

Comment: Was soll denn das sein, der Zuwachs (oder das Wachstum) der Deutschen? Ja wohl nicht die Körperlänge. Die Anzahl der Deutschen wuchs um (oder "wuchs auf", das wäre dann "um 33%"?) 133%?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wer oder was wächst denn wirklich?

Nicht "die Deutschen", denn würden in dieser Formulierung als Individuen um x cm in die Länge wachsen, sondern "die Anzahl/Zahl der Deutschen".

> 133 Prozent beträgt das Wachstum der Zahl der Deutschen, die mit Airbnb reisten.

Weil "das Wachstum der Zahl der Deutschen" fürchterlich klingt,  wird "Wachstum" zum Verb und das Objekt wird zum Subjekt. Kleines "um" nicht vergessen...

> Um 133 Prozent wuchs die Zahl der Deutschen, die mit Airbnb reisten.

Und wenn der Kontext nicht anderes erfordert, wäre eine üblichere Satzstellung:

> Die Zahl der Deutschen, die mit Airbnb reisten, wuchs um 133 Prozent.

Comment: Die schwammige ursprüngliche Formulierung und der lasche Sprachgebrauch lässt offen, ob die Zahl der Deutschen **auf** 133% oder **um** 133% gewachsen sind; letzteres würde mehr als eine Verdopplung bedeuten.

Comment: Stimmt, @guidot, aber zum einen wurde der Punkt im Kommentar zur Frage diskutiert, zum anderen ist im strengeren Sinne das Wachstum immer das, was dazukommt, deshalb in dieser Antwort nur "um".